# Transactions not syncing among nodes in private network when volume is high

Tags: transactions, mining, synchronization, mining-pools

I have 3 nodes are all of them are mining. I called sendTransaction 150k times at a time on node 1. In the txpool of node 1 I see all 150k in pending but in node 2 and node 3 I can see only 50-100 txns. After those are mined it says 0 in both the nodes.

So why is it not syncing properly? Is 150k above capacity.